# How to use the actor model in a Java EE servlet environment?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, model, actor

I am reading about the actor model recently, and I found it's a good programming model for concurrent issues. There are many program languages or tools that use this, like Scala, Jetlang, Klimi, etc.

But how can use these be used in a common web application (a Servlet based one for example)? Servlets are executed in multi-threaded style. Can we use the actor model to eliminate shared date like member variables in a Servlet (or SpringMVC controller etc..)?

Are there any Servlet containers that handle concurrent requests using the actor model?

Answer (score 0):

That's a sort of misconception. You cannot "use actor model in servlet environoment", since application server has already implemented concurrency model, which has to obey Java EE specification.

In particular it is forbidden to have shared data (that can be modified) in a servlet, since one servlet object is used to work with all comming requests. On the other hand, if you have stateful EJB component then you just don't need to care about concurrency issues - thread management is done by EJB container and, in fact, you are not allowed to mess with it.

If you want to write your own server (instead of using existing one based on Java EE), then it is a situation in which it is worth to think of choice of concurrency model.

Although actors are "hot topic" and seems to be "buzzword of the week" right now, search the web for problems and pitfalls connected with usage of actors model. Reality is not that bright as advertised theory.

If you search for performant server-client solution that you can build on look for instance at Netty - that's pretty cool piece of software, that probably would be enough for most of us, even if one wants to build a second Twitter.

Comment: Hi piotr,thanks for your reply,you metion servlet not permit to have shared data,I think this may be not the reality,indeed declare memeber variable in servlet or springMVC controller is widespread,these object is a singleton,so if use memeber variable to share information between request-thread,current need using synchronization or other concurrent collection ect.. I think are there possibility to reconsider our conventional constucts,and use actor model to redesign concurrent to eliminate the shared date.

Comment: There is nothing that would stop you from sharing data between threads in servlet, but, if these data can be changed, then these data will be corrupted one way or the other. If you feel that you must share data between threads then probably servlets are not right technology to use - they were designed as a simple, esentially stateless, HTTP request swallowers.

Comment: Hi piotr,I can give a example:when user request,server need record the access log for audit,log information include access-time,client-ip etc..and in servlet(or filter,interceptor..) I declare List recordList to temp hold the access log records and batch save to database when list size exceed 500.and this recordList object is shared data to all request thread.It is common case in most application,and currently,we need synchronized the shared recordList Object, I am thinking are there some way based actor model to eliminate this shared data and synchronized usage.